# Перевод изображения в бинарный код в виде матрицы JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, изображения, matlab

Можете подсказать как реализовать алгоритм, который будет принимать изображение и конвертировать его в бинарное, чтоб на выходе была матрица нулей и единиц.

Я просто пытаюсь перевести функцию im2bw из matlab на js.

(im2bw(I,level) преобразует изображение I к бинарному изображению BW , заменяя все пиксели во входе отображают с яркостью, больше, чем level со значением 1 (белый) и заменяющий все другие пиксели на значение 0 (черный)).

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я вовсе в этой теме не разбираюсь, но простой гугл запрос на англоговорящем stackoverflow выдает такую информацию

[Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)
(там есть пример реализации функции кодировки в base64)

> I think "Get image data in JavaScript?" answers your question:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
// Create an empty canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

// Copy the image contents to the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// Get the data-URL formatted image
// Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
// original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");}
```

> Pass the img tag to this function. It will return the image in base64 encoding. It will be re-encoded though. So you cannot access the original image data.

Надеюсь это то что ты искал, ответь пожалуйста так это или нет.

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо большое!